# Instantiation of subclass php with existing values of the main class

Tags: php, class, subclass, instantiation

EDIT: Really sorry screwed up original example. More explanation at end.

I am new to OOP finding it useful, finding it confusing.

I have looked and I think this must be a simple question but searched on things like "instantiation of subclass php" but could find nothing on point.

I want to instantiate an object and then later instantiate the subclass. Can I "add" the subclass to the existing instance?

```
class Dog
{
    protected $owner;
    protected $color;

    public function setOwner($owner)
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;
    }
    public function setColor($color)
    {
        $this->color = $color;
    }
}

class Bulldog extends Dog
{
    protected $name;
    protected $typeOfTail;

... set tail....
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

class Beagle extends Dog
{
    protected $name;
    protected $typeOfSpots;

... set spots ....
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}


$myDog = new Dog;
$myDog -> setOwner("Bob");

$myDog1 = new Beagle;
$myDog1 -> setName("name");
```

obviously that will not work but if I do

```
$myDog = new Beagle;
$myDog -> setName("name");
```

I presume that just sets the owner to NULL?

Is there a way to pull the existing values (or duplicate the values) of a class into and instance of a subclass (I suppose I could do some sort of complicated method to pull all the values in but there a lot of them ....) Is this something easy to do in PHP or am I off on a LIMB?

It is 3.30 am and I apologise if this is really dumb but I have hit a wall these last couple of days and am getting behind. This seems like it could be useful in the current project.

**Clarification:** This is a hypothetical example. (No dogs involved with the project.) Say we have a brown dog owned by Fred and we populate an instance of `dog` (pretend it is a big class with lots going on).

The next day someone says "that dog is a beagle" (ok later in the file - this is not a great example) so we want to instantiate a `Beagle` class with the name Suki.

What I want is an instance of `Beagle` that inherits the **already existing** `dog` info.

Sorry once again. Off to bed.

Comment: subclass ?? or the class you extended its already initialize cos its a parent class, now you can easily manipulate parent class from child class

Comment: First, you've already got `setOwner()` and `setColor()` defined in `Dog` class, so you don't need to define them again in `Beagle` class, since `Beagle` extends `Dog`. Second, I don't really understand your problem. Why "obviously that will not work"? You instantiate 2 objects of two classes, set owner to one of them, set color to another... then what?

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry 4am I completely screwed up my example

Comment: You could implement a deep-copy method in `Dog` class, that will take another instance of the same class and copy all attributes. Although it looks ugly to me. From your "The next day someone says that dog is a beagle" it looks like it should be implemented as a `State`. So, either you want something changing over time - `State`, or something that is defined from the beggining - what you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**General solution:** (in case you already know the future subclass)

Just directly create an instance of the subclass. You can use it as an instance of the superclass. But some more information of what you're trying to achieve would be useful.

So it would work like this:

```php
class Dog
{
    protected $owner;
    protected $color;

    public function setOwner($owner)
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;
    }
    public function setColor($color)
    {
        $this->color = $color;
    }
}

class Beagle extends Dog
{
    protected $name;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}


$myDog = new Beagle;

// here we call two methods of the Dog superclass
$myDog->setOwner("Bob");
$myDog->setColor("brown");

// now we call a method of the subclass
$myDog->setName("SomeName");
```

As you can see there is no need to add the methods of the parent class to the subclass again. They will be inherited implicitly and you can just use them on instances of the subclasses as if they are defined within the subclass.

If you omit one of these method calls the property will be `null`, because no default value is assigned to the properties.

**Specific solution:** (in case you don't know the actual subclass)

If you can't create the subclass directly, create a constructor like this:

```
class Dog
{
    protected $owner;
    protected $color;

    public function __construct(Dog $dog = null) {
        if ($dog) {
            foreach ($dog as $key => $value) {
                if (property_exists($this, $key)) {
                    $this->{$key} = $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function setOwner($owner)
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;
    }
    public function setColor($color)
    {
        $this->color = $color;
    }
}

class Beagle extends Dog
{
    protected $name;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}

$dog = new Dog;
$dog->setOwner("Bob");

$beagle = new Beagle($dog);
$beagle->setColor("brown");
```

I did not test the code, so maybe there is still a bug in it, but it should get my point accross.

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry 4am I completely screwed up my example

Comment: @OldMauiMan All answers here still answer your question, even after your edit

Comment: @akasummer it only works if there is one type of dog. Sorry my example was not clear. The point I am trying to make is the information is asynchronous. I know I have a dog before I know which breed if you see what I mean. So the common master class info comes BEFORE you know which subclass you will eventually be populating.

Answer (score 0):

**Parent and child classes**
You can create 2 class, lets call one `ParentClass` and one `ChildClass`. This gives us:

```
class ParentClass
{
}

class ChildClass
{
}
```

As you can see, they are not linked in any way, shape or form, so, we need to *extend* the child class to use the parent, so we now have:

```
class ParentClass
{
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
}
```

Now the child speaks to the parent, so let's add a property to the parent, lets call it `name`:

```
class ParentClass
{
    protected $name; //Protected means it's private, but accessible to children
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
}
```

Now let's add some functionality to the child, a getter and a setter:

```
class ParentClass
{
    protected $name;
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    public function setName($value)
    {
        $this->name = $value;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it uses the `$name` from the parent, meaning it's value is available to the child, so we can do:

```
$childClass = new ChildClass();
$childClass->setName("My Name");
print $childClass->getName(); // prints My Name
```

And get a result!

**Edit**
Extra to show differentiation in the setters:

```
class Dog
{
    protected $owner;
    protected $color;
    protected $name; // I'd put this here as all dogs have a name, right?

    // Put the getters in here as all they do is return, they won't change (hopefully...)
    public function getOwner()
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }
    public function getColor()
    {
        return $this->color;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class Beagle extends Dog
{
    public function setOwner($val) 
    {
        $this->owner = $val;
    }
    public function setColor($val)
    {
        $this->color = $val;
    }
    public function setName($val)
    {
        $this->name = $val;
    }
}

/**
 * Added extra code to setters
 */
class Dalmatian extends Dog
{
    public function setOwner($val)
    {
        $this->owner = "Owner: " . $val;
    }
    public function setColor($val)
    {
        $this->color = "Color: " . $val;
    }
    public function setName($val)
    {
        $this->name = "Name: " . $val;
    }
}
```

As you can see in this example, there are 2 child classes, `Beagle` and `Dalmatian`, each with somewhat different setters for the values.

As the values are not static in the parent class, they will be different in each child, so setting one won't change the other and vica versa.

To keep values from the parent across all subclasses, use static properties as such:

```
class Dog
{
    protected static $owner;
    protected static $color; // Don't know why you'd want this kept, but okay?
}
```

And call using `static::${variable_name};` as opposed to: `$this->{variable_name};`

Comment: Why are the setter and getter coded for the child and not the parent? The parent has the $name attribute. 
If there are other child classes in the future, wouldn't they  to also have the same getter and setter?

Comment: In case you need a different implementation for each in the child classes

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry 4am I completely screwed up my example

Comment: @OldMauiMan, I will add an example for your particular query :P

Comment: There's debate over whether getters and setters should have side effects.  But I can't imagine a case where getName() would be differently implemented for each child class.

Comment: @BryanT, there may be some different way they need to be handled, never know, right?? Haha

Comment: OK sorry peeps. I should have explained that the "dogs" (which are complicated messages and schedules and ordering in real life) can have different attributes. I think the answer may be here already. Trying to keep up clarifying but not sure I am helping. OK this is over and out until I wake up (could not sleep so posted this query - perhaps not the best timing).